# Which read/write Operation is heavier (Shared Preference, Files, Sqlite database)

Tags: java, android, performance, sqlite, android-layout

There are around 10 methods that perform `read/write` operations in a library i am creating. I am using `sharedPreference` to save and get data. I am a bit concerned that is it a wise decision to use `sharedPreference` or should i use `File System` or `sqlite` database.

Kindly guide me which read/write operation is faster.

Comment: Its all depends upon what you wanna achieve?. Eachone has its own use.

Comment: instead of asking community why don't you do a benchmark test with your sample data and tell community/people about your findings.

Comment: it all depends on what you are trying to achieve, but as @Nayan Srivastava wrote - the best solution would be if you test it by yourself.

Comment: Why all this downvotes? It's actually a legit question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html) you should:

**SharedPreferences**

> use a shared preferences file for storing small amounts of information in key-value pairs.

So use SharedPreferences only for some Strings, or variables, not large data assets like big lists. Also is good practice to save here data that has to be accessed often.

**File**

> save a basic file, such as to store long sequences of data that are generally read in order.

File is perfect to save lists. Plus it allows you to save it to external storage or sync it to the cloud.

Finally **SQLite**

> SQLite database to read and write structured data.

Should be used to keep a database of data.

These are the recommended ways of using the three data storage options you have asked for. I hope this answer is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing Local DB(SQLite) is better option, Refer below links for your reference of SQLLite usage.

http://www.ssaurel.com/blog/learn-to-persist-data-on-android-with-sqlite/
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Local-Databases-with-SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: Using Local DB is NOT always a better option. Sometimes it's way faster to use shared preferences for a small amount of data, that has to be accessed quickly.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to save some data on `SharedPreference` when the data you are saving is not **very big**. I recommend using `SharedPreference` in the following scenarios

> when the data you are saving is chatty(used frequently)
>
> when the data is not big in size (as it might cause a bottleneck and slow your app)

But the choice of your storage depends the conditions at hand. The things i think you should consider are your data size, the frequency the data is going to be used and ofcourse read/write time. I hope this helps